# running several comands in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I have some commands I would like to run in the following order:

```
HEADAS=/home/warano/HEASoft/heasoft-6.24/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27
export HEADAS 
alias heainit=". $HEADAS/headas-init.sh" 
heainit
CALDB=/home/warano/NUSTAR/caldb
export CALDB 
source $CALDB/software/tools/caldbinit.sh
```

I put all of these in a script called run-nu_tools.sh, but it does not work so I got this output:

```
./run-nu_tools.sh: line 6: heainit: command not found
```

However *heainit* works if one runs everything in the terminal(step by step) so I want to run all at once, do you have any tips?

Comment: Aliases suck anyway. Use a function.

Comment: This does not help at all.

Comment: Why do you say it does not help? Why do you not want to use a function? Why do you want to use an alias? What happens if you use a function anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that aliases are not expanded if the shell is not interactive:

> **ALIASES:** Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt`.
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

Add the following to your script:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, some part of the prerequisites is wrong. Are you not using Bash after all, perhaps? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash